# Add Image onClick

Tags: javascript

Perhaps not the best title, but here is the issue.

We are creating a submit button, that changes state when user clicks to processing. But wanted to spice it up with a loader image.

So working code is:

```
<a href='#' class='red' onClick="$(this).update('Processing...'); return false;" style="border:0"><img src='img/check.png' style='vertical-align: middle' /> Finish and Pay</a>
```

What I am after is:

```
<a href='#' class='red' onClick="$(this).update('<img src='/img/loader.gif'>Processing...'); return false;" style="border:0"><img src='img/check.png' style='vertical-align: middle' /> Finish and Pay</a>
```

But it isnt complying, I know it must be a bad declaration, just not sure what I am doing wrong. Or if indeed img src needs to be absolute.

Any help cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These quotes are not properly escaped:

```
'<img src='/img/loader.gif'>Processing...'
```

Also, you may want to assign this click function elsewhere (I don't like creating tags inside an attribute, that can be confusing), and I would definitely close that tag.

This might work better:

```
'<img src=\'/img/loader.gif\' />Processing...'
```

Comment: (You may need to do `'<img src=\\'/img/loader.gif\\' />Processing...'`, I'm not really sure at the moment)

Comment: Thats it ( apologies also left /img instead of img ( your code works great ) thankyou

Answer (score 0):

How about using an image button to begin with and changing the src of that?

Comment: I dont like image buttons, I like pure css. Thanks tho.